# GTK Treeview fixed width

Tags: c++, gtk, glade, gtkmm

I have a window structured in the following manner:

Window>VBox>Scrolled Window>Tree View>Columns

My issue arises when I label the last column (it must be a dynamic assignment). If the label winds up being too long, the containing window gets stretched horizontally. Instead, I would like a scroll bar to appear at the bottom of the Scrolled Window to deal with it, leaving the window at its original width.

However, it looks like the closest I can come is fixing the [height](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#ad766f587003dc152e1722cd3be0cedc6) of the Tree View. Surely there's a way to fix the width?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some code to look at? I have done this many times in python and never had any trouble. Also, you link to the fixed height property of the Tree View rows, you actually need the requested width property of the [scrolled window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5e95431f630a226b0b7297e4815ee945). That link also has a link to set the size of [the window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Window.html#ac7bddf34f109fd2ed006ff95f1ae881c).